# How to set default service port/protocol with firewalld module using Ansible?

Tags: linux, ansible, firewalld

I'm looking for a method to set default port/protocol in my Ansible task.

```yaml
# Add port in firewalld
- name: Open port in firewalld
  firewalld:
    port: "{{ foo_setted_port_var | default (8080/tcp) }}"
    state: enabled
    permanent: yes
    immediate: yes
    zone: "{{ setted_firewalldzone_var | default (public) }}"
```

- when I put on line `port : [...] default (8080/tcp) [...]`
  output is : `The error was: 'tcp' is undefined`
- when I put on line `port : [...] default (8080) [...]`
  output is : `improper port format (missing protocol?)`

When I precise in my `foo_setted_port_var` `8080/tcp` it works. However I really want to set my port by default in my task code before in my var file.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

According [providing default values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#providing-default-values) and [`firewalld` module – Manage arbitrary ports/services with firewalld](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/firewalld_module.html#examples) the syntax should be

```yaml
# Add port in firewalld
- name: Open port in firewalld
  firewalld:
    port: "{{ foo_setted_port_var | default('8080/tcp') }}"
    state: enabled
    permanent: yes
    immediate: yes
    zone: "{{ setted_firewalldzone_var | default('public') }}"
```

Without the quotes (`'`) the term `tcp` or `public` would be interpreted as variable name and tried to be looked up for content.

You can see this from the error message

```
'tcp' is undefined
```

and observe the behavior with the following test.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    PUBLIC: "public"

  tasks:

  - name: Show values
    debug:
      msg:
        - "{{ TXT | default(PUBLIC) }}"
        - "{{ TXT | default('PUBLIC') }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show values] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - public
  - PUBLIC
```

The other error message

```
improper port format
```

relates to [Parameter: port](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/firewalld_module.html#parameter-port) which needs to be `string` and not `int`.